# show and switch to a window in win32

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

I have a child window which sometimes is needed to show.In my winform project somehow this windows can be focused to user. i tried `mywindow.focus()` but it didn't work. So i want to use win32 api for showing this window. i heard something like these:

```
[DllImport("User32")]
 public static extern void SwitchToThisWindow(IntPtr hWnd, bool fAltTab);

     public static void ShowAndSwitchWindow(IntPtr MainWindowHandle)
     {
   ShowWindow(MainWindowHandle.ToInt32(), SW_MAXIMIZE);
   SwitchToThisWindow(MainWindowHandle, true);
      }
```

But i cant understand how to use that in my project?????

my window is like that:(remember this is not main window.this window is called from another window called MainWindow)

```
               show_meaning s = new show_meaning(x);
                s.Show();
```

I am not used to in win32 api.
Can anyone help me ????

Comment: `s.Show()` should make the window visible, and give it focus if it is modal with respect to the currently-active window.  Forcing it to have focus is a bad thing, IMO, as your user might be in a completely different application and may not appreciate having his keystrokes suddenly and without warning directed into your application.  (This is called "focus stealing."  From a user experience standpoint, it is a very bad idea.)

Answer (score 0):

You should call SetForegroundWindow and ShowWindow() instead of ShowWindow() only.

```
[DllImport("User32")]
public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hwnd);
```